# Android Blurry image

Tags: android, imageview, image-quality

I have an image saved in my database which is perfectly fine I am able to retrieve it, but the problem is that the image quality definitely has been lowered.

This is my code

String server_url = "http://192.168.8.100/jmiappphp/fetchImage.php?id="+user_id;

```
    ImageRequest imageRequest = new ImageRequest(server_url,
            new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
                    profile_image.setImageBitmap(response);
                }
            }, 50, 50, ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP, null, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(User_nav.this,"Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            error.printStackTrace();

        }
    });
    UserImageSingleton.getInstance(User_nav.this).addToRequestQue(imageRequest);
```

UserImageSingleton

```
 private static UserImageSingleton mInstance;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private static Context mCtx;
private UserImageSingleton(Context context){
    mCtx = context;
    requestQueue = getRequestQueue();

}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue(){
    if(requestQueue==null){
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return requestQueue;
}
public static synchronized UserImageSingleton getInstance(Context context){
    if(mInstance==null){
        mInstance = new UserImageSingleton(context);
    }
    return mInstance;
}
public <T> void addToRequestQue(Request<T> request){
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

[image: This is the activity with the imageView]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem could be, that your max size is set to 50.

```
}, 50, 50, ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP, null, new Response.ErrorListener() {
```

You could use a higher value for the size. 
If you set those two values to zero there will be no scaling.
I hope that solves the problem.